# How to move a btrfs balance operation to the background?

Tags: btrfs

I have remoted into my DIY NAS, and have run:

```bsh
sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/tank
```

However, from some napkin math, it will take about a week to complete from the data from:

```
sudo btrfs balance status /mnt/tank
```

As I didn't run the `btrfs balance start` operation with `--bg`, how can I move it to the background now?

I have tried `Ctrl + Z` as well as entering `disown`, both to no avail.

I have also checked the documentation on `btrfs balance pause`, however `btrfs balance resume` does not have a `--bg` flag it seems.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Your two best options are probably to login again with `ssh` and either:

1. `btrfs cancel` the `btrfs balance` command and run it again in with `--bg`, or
2. pause it, run `tmux`, and resume it in `tmux` (or use `screen` instead of `tmux`).

Answer (score 0):

I put mine on a cron job that runs in the background every hour. I'm not sure if this is the right way, but it does run in the background. Here's my command:

```bash
btrfs balance start -mconvert=raid1 -dconvert=raid0 / -f
```

My setup is RAID0, not RAID1, but you get the idea.